# Sliding border from right to left using CSS

Tags: html, css, sliding

I have a header that I want to have a border on that slides from right to left on hover, using pure CSS if that's possible.

At the moment, I can get a border that slides from left to right using the following CSS:

```
#header a:after {
content: '';
display: block;
border-bottom: 3px solid $(header.hover.color);
width: 0;
-webkit-transition: 1s ease;
        transition: 1s ease;
}

#header a:hover:after { width: 100%; }
```

Has anyone a good solution for accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can position your `:after` element to the right

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}
#header a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

#header a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you! I feel silly for not thinking of using <code>right:</code>

Comment: Since you are only animating the width property I would write the transition property like this: transition: width 1s ease;

Comment: Future readers: note that animating width isn't considered best practice. Try using a combination of "overflow: hidden" on the parent and "transform: translateX(-100%)" on the child. This allows you to slide it in without altering the box model which results in a higher FPS animation.

Answer (score 1):

Give all:

```
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
        transition: 1s all ease;
```